# A question about Markov Processes

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

[image: Stem of the question]

Hi Guys,

```
I have no idea how to start this problem.
```

Questions are below:

1.What is the probability that the next 3 symbols are digits?

2.What is the probability that the next 3 symbols are the same?

3.What is the probability that the next 2 symbols are digits and the 2
symbols after that are letters?

4.Predict the probability that the symbol two away from the current letter is also a letter.
 Thanks ahead!

---

Comment: Starting with L, you want LLL  Using the Markov property, $P(L_1L_2L_3|L_0) = P(L_1|L_0)P(L_2|P_1)P(L_3|L_2) = .7^3.$ This answers (1) and is one of three terms in the answer to (2). For (4) you may want a power of the transition matrix. Now it is _your turn_ to do some of the work.

Comment: Hi Bruce, for question 1, I got P(D1D2D3|L0) = 0.1*0.1*0.1, and for question 2 I got P(D1D2D3|L0)+P(L1L2L3|L0)+P(O1O2O3|L0) = 0.3^3+0.7^3+0.2^3 right?

Answer (score 2):

To help you get started.

Here is how I will approach the first part.

We know the current symbol is a letter.

\begin{align}&P(X_3 = \text{digit}, X_2 = \text{digit},X_1 = \text{digit}|X_0=\text{letter})\\
&=P(X_3 = \text{digit}|X_2 = \text{digit})P(X_2 = \text{digit}|X_1 = \text{digit})P(X_1 = \text{digit}|X_0 = \text{letter})
\end{align}

You should be able to read off those values.

Comment: HI, Goh, I have trouble understanding the matrix the teacher gave me. What is 0.7 in the matrix mean?

Comment: The row represents previous state, the columns represent current state. $0.7$ represent means the probability that the current state is a letter given that the previous state is a letter.

Comment: Hi Goh, question 1, I got P(D1D2D3|L0) = 0.1*0.1*0.1=0.003and for question 2 I got P(D1D2D3|L0)+P(L1L2L3|L0)+P(O1O2O3|L0) = 0.3^3+0.7^3+0.2^3 =0.36?

Comment: How did you get the three $0.1$ for question $1$?

Comment: Reading from the matrix,the probability of  the current state is letter, next state is digit is 0.1? Oh I get it, so should it be 0.1*0.3*0.3?

Comment: Great, that is correct for $P(D_1|L_0)$, now what about $P(D_2|D_1)$?

Comment: Yup, $0.1(0.3)(0.3)$. and oh, btw, $0.1 \times 0.1 \times 0.1 \neq 0.003$. The rest can be done similarly. Just be careful not to make careless mistakes.

Comment: so, P(D1|L0) is 0.1*0.3*0.3?  I think I am confused now. Why P(D1|L0) = 0.1*0.3*0.3? I thought P(X3=digit|X2=digit)P(X2=digit|X1=digit)P(X1=digit|X0=letter) = 0.1*0.3*0.3.

Comment: $P(D_1|L_0)=0.1$. Your last statement is correct.

Comment: So, the first question is 0.009? And for the second question 2 P(D1D2D3|L0)+P(L1L2L3|L0)+P(O1O2O3|L0) = 0.1*0.3*0.3+0.7^3+0.2*0.4*0.4?

Comment: Yes for first question. Congrats, you can now solve the whole problem. Just go slow, write down all your step and be careful.

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer, is the answer now correct?

Comment: yes, I think you have learned the material. The rest is about how careful you are.

Comment: For question three I got 0.1*0.3*0.3*0.5*0.7 = 0.00315.

Comment: For question four I got 0.7*0.7+0.1*0.5+0.2*0.5 = 0.64?

Comment: I didn't check the final answer as they are not that important. but for question $3$. You are multiplying $5$ numbers?

Comment: Oh my bad. We want to know that P(D1D2L3L4|L0)and it is 0.1*0.3*0.5*0.7 =0.0105?

Comment: seems reasonable. crucial take away for this question is for markov chain model, given the present state, the next state is entirely depending on the present state and doesn't depend on previous state.  mathjax resources, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 try to include attempts or reason why you are stuck in future post and you will get more positive response.

Comment: I will! Thanks for the help! It is my second time using stackexchange and It is a great resource.